# Multiple directories on one FTP site?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I have various directories spread accross my system. I would like to offer these directores on one FTP site, in a top level directory.

So if I have for example

c:\test\docs
c:\xxx\test\1
c:\books\pdfs

I can offer just the docs, 1, and pdfs directories without needing to share the top level directories.

Then someone connecting via FTP would see the docs, 1 and pdfs directories available for browsing.

Is this possible to set up with IIS FTP on server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setup one FTP site and link each of these directories as Virtual Directories from within the IIS FTP manager.  For security make sure the permissions separate these out from accessibility by using the R/W allow and deny rights.

Comment: I tried this, however when I connect to the FTP site I just see the empty directory, none of the virtual directories I have set up. I only have anonymous access setup with pass through authentication....am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try changing to one of the directories, this might be the NTFS permissions on that directory unable to display.   see if you can run the command 'cd directoryname' and if it accepts in order to run a process of elimination.

Comment: OK, I get the error "Error details: File system denied the access.". I get that error when trying to cd to the directory, but in the root directory it does not show up with ls. How should I grant permissions?

Comment: One of the directories not having permission is weird, because previously I just added it as the main site and it worked fine

Comment: from explorer, right click the directory check the ntfs permissions, be sure that the logged in user has the appropriate permissions to allow read and director listing if required.